# Collecting AngularJS and Ionic crashes

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, crash, crash-reports

The question is really easy.
Is there a web service that provide us a structure to collect all client crashes?

Our clients are developed using AngularJS and Ionic and we would like to unify the way to collect these logs.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Bugsnag](https://bugsnag.com) for this in my Ionic apps.

*Note: I'm not an affiliate or anything, just like the service.*

*Note2: It's free for open source and non-profit organizations.*

Comment: Did you use the normale browser javascript of Bugsnag? Or did you write your own? Please provide some snippets.

Comment: Yes, normal JS, nothing special.

Comment: Did you get this working? I'm trying to do the same, but it doesn't seem to be working at all.